# Confidence Interval Probabilty

Tags: probability

> 1) We have discovered a new method to produce a liquid containing
>   Zinc. We measure the concentration μ four times independently (from
>   the same solution) and find the values
>
> **0.3, 0.33, 0.3, 0.27**
>
> a) Assuming that the standard deviation of the measurement error is
>   0.02 (when we make one measurement) estimate μ and give a 90%-confidence interval.
>
> **Answer**:
>
> We assume the measurement errors to be normal with zero expectation.
>   The estimate for μ is
>
> $μ_X = (X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4)/4 = (0.3 + 0.33 + 0.3 + 0.27)/4 = 0.3.$
>
> The same procedure as usual leads to a confidence interval
>
> $[0.3 - b_\text{standard deviation}/\sqrt{n},\, 0.3 + b_\text{standard deviation}/\sqrt{n}]$
>
> where the standard deviation equals $0.02$ and $\sqrt{n} = 2$,
>   whilst $b$ is defined by the equation
>
> $P(−b \leq N(0, 1)\leq b) = 90\%.$
>
> The last equation above is equivalent to $\lambda(b) = 0.95$ which we can solve with the help of a table and find $b = 1.645$. Hence the $90\%$ confidence interval is equal
>   to $[0.3 − 0.0164, 0.3 + 0.0164] = [0.2836, 0.3164]$. The true
>   concentration is thus between $0.2836$ and $0.3164$ with at least $95\%$
>   probability.

My question is how were they able to get $95\%$ probability and $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find $b$ such that $P(−b \leq N(0, 1)\leq b) = 0.9$.  From the symmetry of the normal density function, this means that 
$$P(b < N(0,1) < \infty) = P(-\infty < N(0,1) < b) = 0.05$$
since $10\%$ of the area under the normal density function is outside the
interval $[-b,b]$.  You have a table of values of the cumulative standard
normal distribution function, which tells you the value of
$$P(-\infty < N(0,1) \leq b) = P(-\infty < N(0,1) < b) + P(−b \leq N(0, 1)\leq b)
= 0.05 + 0.9 = 0.95$$
So you look in the table and find that $b = 1.645$ gives a value of $0.9495$,
just a *little* less than the desired $0.9500$,
and so the exact value of $b$ is a *tad* more that $1.645$.

Answer (score 2):

$0.95$ comes from the fact that $\lambda(b) = 1 - \lambda(-b)$ and that you want $b$ to satisfy $\lambda(b) - \lambda(-b) = 0.9$. The number $b$ is found by looking up in the table of values of $\lambda$.

(I assume that $\lambda$ is the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution with zero mean and variance $1$.)

Comment: Yes, you assumed right. But how do you know what b is? It says in the answer that b = 1.645. But in the table it shows thats 45% and I still don't know how they came up with 1.645.

Comment: I am not sure which table you use, but I found [this](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrl/normal_cdf.pdf) which shows $b = 1.64$ corresponds to $0.9495$.

Comment: No wonder, thank you! sorry for my ignorance, but i still dont know how they knew to look up 95 % . You said 0.95  comes from the fact that λ(b)=1−λ(−b). But how is that what will make λ(b)=1−λ(−b) equal to 95%?

Comment: $\lambda(b) = 1 - \lambda(-b)$ is a property of $\lambda$. The confidence interval you want satisfies $\lambda(b) - \lambda(-b) = 0.9$. Solving these two equations for $\lambda(b)$ and $\lambda(-b)$ will give $\lambda(b) = 0.95$ and $\lambda(-b) = 0.05$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully certain what the question is, but for I'll guess that it's something like this: The probability that a normally distributed random variable is less than its expected value plus $1.645$ standard deviations is about $95\%$, so how is that related to the $90\%$ figure mentioned after that?

$$
\Pr(Z<1.645) = 0.95.
$$
So
$$
\Pr(Z>1.645) = 0.05.
$$
By symmetry, then,
$$
\Pr(Z<-1.645) = 0.05.
$$
So you have $5\%$ of the probability in the upper tail and $5\%$ in the lower tail.  That makes $10\%$.  So $90\%$ remains in the middle.